# Disable autocomplete on Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, autocomplete

I have an app built in HTML5 and wrapped in PhoneGap ..

I want to **disable** Android's autocomplete (Of the keyboard)

when starting the application,

how can I do this?

*Thanks in advance*

My PhoneGap Manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.MyApp.XXX"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
<supports-screens 
    android:largeScreens="true" 
    android:normalScreens="true" 
    android:smallScreens="true" 
    android:resizeable="true" 
    android:anyDensity="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.MyApp.XXX.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: can you be more specific? What do you mean android's auto complete? Are you talking about word suggestions from the keyboard? or auto complete in form elements?

Comment: word suggestions from the keyboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'oninput' event in the input, ran the following function:

```
function RefreshAutoComplete(elm) {
    elm.keyup();
    elm.focus();
}
```

I run the auto complete manually, and it works

Thank you all for the help

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
<input type="text" id="myText" name="myText" autocomplete='off'/>
```

Or

```
someFormElm.setAttribute( "autocomplete", "off" );
```

Comment: I've tried both options, none of them cancels the auto complete

Comment: Maybe I'm missing settings I can access it in PhoneGap? I'll add it to the question

Comment: This is the correct answer in my opinion, but there is a bug in Chrome for Android which results in the browser not respecting the autocomplete / autocorrect HTML 5 attributes. It appears to just recently have been fixed and hopefully should be released in an update soon.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=303883&q=autocorrect&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Also feel free to Star the issue to help boost the ranking...

Answer (score 1):

You can add this CSS line to the elements where the autocomplete has to be off :

```
-webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
```

In Xperia phones, it will disable autocomplete, dictionnary, etc...

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. [There are](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=keyboard&c=apps) [many](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gokeyboard&feature=search_result) [keyboards](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchtype.swiftkey.phone.trial&feature=search_result) [available](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dasur.slideit&feature=search_result) for Android, and as far as I know, there is no standard way of telling them to avoid any auto-complete feature  using HTML5. As Arash suggested, you can do this using native android elements, but HTML5 doesn't provide an interface for this. The only think you can disable is in-browser autocomplete, using `autocomplete=off` as others have suggested.

I think you need to ask yourself if it will really enhance user experience if they can't use their favourite fast typing features of a keyboard that they may have paid good money for?

Comment: But Android Autocomplete destroys My Autocomplete, as well as the autocomplete=off does not work

Comment: The issue with autocomplete from the keyboards, is that if messes up typeahead plugins (this one for example http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/typeaheads) so there is a definite need to disable it for certain fields.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="textSample"/>
```

**JS:**

```
$("#textSample").autocomplete({ disabled: true });
```

OR

```
$("#textSample").autocomplete({
  change: function(event, ui) {
       $(this).autocomplete("destroy");
  }
});
```

OR

See more info about [How to Turn Off Form Autocompletion?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion)

Comment: It deletes the autocomplete of my input, not the Android Keyboard